# Twitch.tv Movies as Highslide SWF Objects

Tags: video, flash, embed, highslide

Trying to embed a Twitch.tv video (e.g. http://www.twitch.tv/aa2233aa/c/2236969) in a Highslide.js popup.

I can do something like this, with an iframe, no problem:

```
<td class="top" colspan="3" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe', width: 1280, height: 720, objectLoadTime: 'after', src: 'http://www.twitch.tv/aa2233aa/c/2236969' })">
```

But if I just want the video/stream itself, it's problematic. Twitch.tv has object embed share code on the page itself:

```
<object bgcolor='#000000' data='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/archive_embed_player.swf' height='378' id='clip_embed_player_flash' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='620'>
  <param name='movie' value='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/archive_embed_player.swf'>
  <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'>
  <param name='allowNetworking' value='all'>
  <param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'>
  <param name='flashvars' value='start_volume=25&chapter_id=2236969&auto_play=false&title=poro%25E8%2587%25AA%25E7%2588%2586%25E4%25BA%2586%2521%2521%2521&channel=aa2233aa'>
</object>
```

Here's an example of the Highslide technique I'm trying to replicate: http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/flash-with-move+close-buttons.html

Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work. I'd post some of my attempts but there have been so many permutations at this point that it would just clutter up this post even moreso.

Anyhow, a helpful hand would be appreciated. As usual, I'm not necessarily looking for direct answers, but hints and pointing me in the right direction are good! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Twitch.tv only provides you with the old object code, you need to put the share code in its own HTML page, save the page, and open it in a Highslide iframe popup.

```
<td class="top" colspan="3" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe', width: 1280, height: 720, objectLoadTime: 'after', src: 'video.html' })">
```

(You probably need to adjust the width and height of the popup.)